# Material design colors

Tags: android, colors, material-design

I am trying to implement material design. Is there a constants for colors? For example, i can use @color/material_grey_850, but when I try to use @color/material_orange_500 - compilation failes. 
Can I use constants or I must use only values (#9E9E9E and #FF9800 in this case)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create all the colors you want on the `colors.xml` file, but, if you want ALL the Material colors, you can use this library:

> https://github.com/bassaer/MaterialDesignColors

As soon as you compile it, you will be able to use every Material color just writing something like `@color/blue_200`

Answer (score 0):

> You can use constants defined in your colors.xml.  For instance:

```
<color name="my_button_green">@color/color_button_green</color>

<color name="color_button_green>#006600</color>
```